# How to send messages using a variable

Tags: php

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
// $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Host = "mail.infysky.com";
$port = $mail->Port = 465;
//echo "<br />";
$mail->IsHTML(false);

$name        = "'" . $params["txtName"] . "'";
$email       = "'" . $params["txtEmailID"] . "'";
$department  = "'" . $params["selDepartment"] . "'";
$designation = "'" . $params["selDesignation"] . "'";
$leave       = "'" . $params["selLeave"] . "'";
$dateFrom    = "'" . $params["txtDate1"] . "'";
$dateTo      = "'" . $params["txtDate2"] . "'";
$reason      = "'" . $params["txtReason"] . "'";

$mail->SetFrom("karthik.hansi@infysky.com", 'infy SKY');
$mail->Subject = "90%";
$mail->Body = "Message for leave apply \n NAME:        $name;\n E-MAIL       
$email;\n DEPARTMENT:  $department; \n DESIGNATION: $designation;\n LEAVE 
TYPE:  $leave;\n DATE FROM:   $dateFrom;\n DATE TO:     $dateTo;\n REASON:      
$reason; ";

$mail->AddAddress();  //To Address
$mail->Send();
```

How to send messages from the variable in AddAddress in PHP Mailer.
In AddAddress I want to send dynamic messages to the entered client.

Comment: Mail Successfully sent through this code just I want to Send with $email in AddAddress

Comment: BRO I GOT SOLUTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `$mail->addAddress($email)`? See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Yes I tried but I am Getting Invalid Email Address

Comment: Can you print out or var_dump() the contents of your `$email` variable?

Comment: I am Getting email address Which I have Passed through var_dump() but still getting this error message     <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address: 'sunita.patil@infysky.com''

Comment: It appears that the email address in the `$email` variable is enclosed in single quotes ('). Can you check?

Comment: If See this  " ' " . $params["txtEmailID"] . " ' "; here the string coated with single quotes. But Now What I do Any idea.

Comment: Just this: `$mail->addAddress($params["txtEmailID"])` (or something similar) -- the parameter should just be a valid address. If it is enclosed in quotes it is no longer valid.

Comment: This will also work: `$mail->addAddress($params["txtEmailID"], $params["txtName"])`